# How to draw a participant inside another participant in a PlantUML sequence diagram?

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram, plantuml

Confluence + plantuml,
https://plantuml.com/sequence-diagram

```
@startuml
Alice -> Bob: Authentication Request
Bob --> Alice: Authentication Response

Alice -> Bob: Another authentication Request
Alice <-- Bob: Another authentication Response
@enduml
```

How to draw Chris inside the box of Alice pls ? So box of Alice contains box of Chris. Thx !

Comment: What do you mean by "How to draw Chris inside the box of Alice"? Maybe an image might help

Comment: Right now there's 1 rectangle for Alice, i want to have another rectangle inside that one, have text "Chris"

Comment: Can you explain in prose what business or system interaction you would like to model?

Comment: You might post a manual drawing of what you try to achieve. This way it's absolutely unclear what you want. Inside the box can be interpreted in many ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use box,

This is the sample from the doc
https://plantuml.com/sequence-diagram

```
@startuml

box "Internal Service" #LightBlue
    participant Bob
    participant Alice
end box
participant Other

Bob -> Alice : hello
Alice -> Other : hello

@enduml
```

it works for my simple case.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think that drawing participants inside other participants is possible with PlantUML.

More importantly, though : It is not UML-compliant. Participants in a UML sequence diagramme are atomic and there are no "sub-participants".

But I have a strong feeling that you could express your idea with a separate participant called "Chris" who is being invoked by "Alice". You could use different participants declarations that PlantUML offers to demonstrate their roles (e.g., you could make "Alice" a controller and "Chris" an interface, if those are their roles in your system) if it is important for your diagramme's audience to understand what Chris is doing (i.e., a white-box approach to looking at Alice). However, if it is not important for your audience to understand that Alice has sub-components who carry out parts of her activities (i.e., a black-box approach to Alice), then there is no need to mention Chris at all, in my opinion.

So, if you have to create a UML diagramme, the above might help you. If you do not have to call your diagramme a "UML sequence diagramme", then you can draw whatever you want (except with a language-specific modeling tool like PlantUML).

Comment: I think you should emphasize the statement in the brackets about not being UML compliant. The OP should use a drawing tool and not an UML tool if he wants to do that.

Comment: Good point! I have slightly adapted the text. Feel free to add your own edits if you think it is not clear.

Comment: Looks ok this way :-)